# Convert File System Website to IIS Website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, visual-studio-2010

We recently migrated from VS 2008 to VS 2010. The migration went fine, except for our web project. Before, in VS 2008, the site showed up as http://localhost/Website. Now, it appears as C:...\Website. It appears that when we did the migration, VS started to treat it as a file system website.

I've tried removing the existing site and re-adding it as an existing website, but it still displays it as C:...\Website. Is there any way to convert it back to show it as a http://localhost/website, and run through IIS, as opposed to the default ASP.NET Development Server?

Comment: You should post this on serverfault.  Not really a programming question

Comment: I figured it was a programming question as it relates to Visual Studio and its projects.

Comment: @Silmaril89: of course it's programming related - Visual Studio 2010 broke the site. He's going to have to use Visual Studio to fix the problem, as well.

Comment: @Saunders: that doesn't make it programming related. I still think it should be on serverfault, but I won't argue about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Special thanks to John Dundon at Microsoft for helping me resolve the issue. Here's what he said:

> Thanks for all the details.  This actually sounds like a quirky behavior
>   in VS that I think I can help you work
>   around.
>
> I believe the reason it’s remembering
>   to use the local development server is
>   because it got stored in the SUO file.
>   So there are two possible ways to fix
>   this:
>
> 1. Re-open your solution from source control as an administrator on the
>      machine with IIS installed and
>      everything should get downloaded to
>      its right place
> 2. If you close VS, delete the SUO file (note – this will erase some
>      settings about the state of your
>      solution but shouldn’t cause any real
>      data loss), and then re-open the
>      solution, it should ask you to
>      re-download that particular web site
>      and will try to make it an IIS web
>      site again.
>
> Note however though that since your
>   virtual directory already exists on
>   your machine, it’s going to ask you if
>   you want to use it – I’m assuming you
>   do, but it will overwrite any files
>   when it does.
>
> Let me know if this works for you (and
>   while you technically shouldn’t need
>   to, it may be a good idea to back up
>   any work you’ve done in this
>   enlistment that hasn’t been checked in
>   prior to trying this).

I followed his advice and removed my SUO file and re-opened the solution. The website was automatically fixed as http://localhost/Website and it also checked out the .SLN file as well, and when I checked it in, it fixed the issue for other developers as well. Hope this solution helps out others as well with this quirky issue.

Comment: My file system based projects are not in source control and when I tried deleteing the suo file and restarting VS2008, it just loaded the same file system based projects.Any workaround this?

Comment: chugh97, I'm not sure. This was VS2010, so I don't know if it made a difference there or not.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the project properties, on the Web tab. You'll be able to select whether to use IIS or the development server, and which virtual directory to use.

Comment: I see in the start options where I can change it from "Use default Web server" to "Use custom server" and set the Base URL: as http://localhost/Website. That does allow it to run properly, but it's more of a work around. Is there a way to permanently fix it? Or are you referring to a different area?

Comment: @Noah: how is that a workaround? Are there other differences between an IIS site and a file-based site?

Comment: I'm not sure what the differences are. With that approach though, each dev box needs to be setup to point to a localhost IIS directory through the project properties, as opposed to just having the project work initially. I sent the Q to MS to see if they could tell me the difference between the 2.

Comment: @Noah: doesn't that setting persist in the project or solution? If it does, then there would be no per-developer setup.

Comment: I got the proper fix from MS. I will paste the answer below.